# Videos stop playing after 16 consecutive videos played

Tags: ios, cordova, video

I'm working on a phonegap app deployed to iOS and Android. There are a ton of videos in the app, some are included with the package and others are download and stored locally in the background. After you play 16 videos in a row just fine, the 17th video presents the video div with the play button with a line through it.

I've tried changing different things, but with no success. Below is some code that generate the video div:

```
        html += "<video id='popoverVideo' width='"+(globals.screenWidth-h)+"' height='"+(globals.screenHeight-h/2)+"' style='position:absolute;background:black;left:"+left+"px;top:"+top+"px;' controls='true' webkit-playsinline>"+
              "<source src='"+globals.wwwRootPath+video.path+"' type='video/mp4' codecs='avc1, mp4a'>"+
              "Your browser does not support the video tag."+
            "</video>";
```

The problem only occurs in the iOS version. The Android version has no issues playing more than 16 videos in a row consecutively.

I've also checked in another phonegap app of a developer I work with and his Video code is very different than mine and his app has the exact same issue and he only has four videos included in the app. You play those four videos though 16 times cycling through them one at a time and on the 17th play, play button with a line through it.

One other important note, if you background the app and then bring it back into the foreground, resets your count and you can play another 16 videos in a row, or even the 17th video you had up with the line through play button will automatically start playing with the app is foregrounded. Maybe I need to force a cache release when the video is stopped?

Comment: What version of iOS does this happen on? Also, does it happen in the simulator, or just the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're following the best practices for mobile devices:

**[4.8.10.16 Best practices for authors using media elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html)**

> Playing audio and video resources on small devices such as set-top
>   boxes or mobile phones is often constrained by limited hardware
>   resources in the device. For example, a device might only support
>   three simultaneous videos. For this reason, it is a good practice to
>   release resources held by media elements when they are done playing,
>   either by being very careful about removing all references to the
>   element and allowing it to be garbage collected, or, even better, by
>   removing the element's src attribute and any source element
>   descendants, and invoking the element's load() method.

Here's some code that will do this:

```
var video = document.getElementById('videoID');
var child = null;

while(child = video.firstChild) {
    if(child.nodeName === 'SOURCE') {
        child.src = '';
    }

    video.removeChild(child);
}

video.load();
```